# How to split sentence into parts which consists of spaces as well?

Tags: java, regex, split

hi My name is  "IS J" and
I need to split into array which consists of
hi
My
name
is 
IS J
and

I have used java string split, but it is not what i need ,
I used

```
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w|\"[^\"]*\"");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        String s = m.group();
        Log.i("result", + s);
    }
```

but s returns numbers , I need strings

Comment: You really should provide code showing that you have at least tried to solve the problem, and from there we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting won't be easy, but you can do it yourself, by matching either words or quoted strings, e.g.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+|\"[^\"]*\"");
```

Search your string for this pattern, and add the matches to a List.
(If you want to, you can then create an array from that list)

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w|\"[^\"]*\"");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            String s = m.group();
            Log.i("result", " " + s);

        }

s prints numbers. I could not understand what methodI need to use?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Thanks ,but 
hi My name is "IS J" and 23,5 
it splits 23 and 5 ,others works as expected,how to exclude ,

Comment: @I.S.S.J see update